# Are storyboards widely used on iOS apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I am currently developing a iOS framework for other developers to use. I intend to use "ECSlidingViewController" framework and add it a webView to that Slide-Up. I already have it working on two projects but they all use storyboards in it.

My search for sample projects to test my framework raised a big question. 9 out of 10 of this samples didn't use storyboard.

So my question is: Should I start developing my framework for non-storyboard apps or is this situation only happening in sample projects.

Comment: I must say I'm a self-made iOS developer and I'm struggling with the transition from Android to iOS. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean by sample projects.

All applications prior to iOS 5.0 are non-storyboard type.

If you intend to support versions prior to 5.0 only, you have to leave out the option to support storyboard.

If you are supporting older as well as 5.0 + versions you have to build it for storyboard as well as non storyboard applications.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. By sample projects I mean free source code projects I found browsing the web. I am currently supporting only 5.0 and 6.0 apps. So you think I should support both because non storyboard apps are still being developed nowadays.

Comment: You can download storyboard compatible apps. You can download samples from http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1